# Нужно сделать автоматическое увеличение числа

Tags: php, javascript

Хочу сделать игровой проект, где будет своя внутренняя валюта. Хочу сделать, чтобы при проигрыше внутренней валюты, она автоматически начала пополняться и останавливаться на фиксированном ограничении.

Допустим, у игрока 50 фишек, он их проиграл, стало 0 - в этот момент они должны начать пополняться и останавливаться, допустим, на 50. Можно по 10 каждые 10 минут, можно по 1 каждую минуту, непринципиально,если кто понял о чем речь, подкиньте, пожалуйста, код. Можно формальный, хотя бы чтобы разобраться.
Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно как-то отметить время, когда всё потрачено до нуля и включить игроку временный режим «накопление денег за время».

Далее количество валюты становится функцией времени:

```
start = XXX; // время когда упало до 0
mode = "earning"; // игрок находится в режиме накопления за время
now = (new Date).getTime(); // время сейчас
money = Math.floor((now - start) / N) * K;
if( money > 50) {
    mode = "game"; // больше нет режима накопления
    money = 50;
}
```

Продумайте момент, когда во время накопления за деньги, игрок как-то ещё умудрился заработать несколько монет – что делать тогда?

---

Поясню строку `money = Math.floor((now - start) / N) * K;`. Это школа, линейная алгебра – нам нужна функция, растущая от `0` в точке `start`. В простом варианте это `y = k * (x - start)`, где `k` некий коэф. скорости роста. Но так будут дробные значения, а вы пишете в вопросе про дискретные – «*по 10 каждые 10 минут, можно по 1 каждую минуту*».

Т.е. график роста не наклонная линия, а ступеньки по целым значениям. Поэтому добавлено округление:

[image: графики]

Как подобрать коэффициенты `N` и `K`. Не углубляясь в объяснение, вот рецепт. Если надо чтобы раз в минуту (60 секунд) на 1, делим на `N=60` и можно не умножать. Если раз в 10 минут (600 секунд) на 10, делим на `N=600`, и умножаем на `K=10`.

Comment: Если зашел в игру - то пополнение идет, но если лимит(50 монет), превышен, то накопление приостанавливает.Спасибо за код:)

Comment: И можешь пояснить четвертую строчку?)А конкретнее: ((now - start) / N) * K;А если ещё конкретнее - мне непонятны N и K, я в js не особо ещё)

Comment: Пояснил в ответе.